# Showing that a circle is "tangent" to the $x$-axis if and only if $\left|k\right| = r$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The problem is this:

> to show that a circle of radius $r$ and center $(h, k)$ intersects the $x$-axis at exactly one point if and only if $\left|k\right| = r$.

Using geometrical intuition, this is easy to see. When a circle's bottom or top is just touching the $x$-axis, its center is one radius away. (Note that I put "tangent" in quotes because I'm using a definition which captures one aspect of tangency, but doesn't hold in the case of, say, intersecting lines.)

I'm having some trouble with the forward direction of this statement.

#### My attempt so far

Suppose that the circle $C$ touches the $x$-axis at exactly one point. That is, suppose that $(\alpha, 0) \in C$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x, 0) \notin C$ for all $x \neq \alpha$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}$). Then

$$
\begin{align*}
(\alpha - h)^2 + (0 - k)^2 &= r^2
\\ \Rightarrow (\alpha - h)^2 + k^2 &= r^2.
\end{align*}
$$

Somehow I need to use the fact that the only $\alpha$ which works is $h$... but how can I show that $\alpha = h$?

#### The backward direction

Suppose $\left|k\right| = r$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
(h - h)^2 + (0 - k)^2 &= k^2
\\ &= \left|k\right|^2
\\ &= r^2
\\ \Rightarrow (h, 0) &\in C
\end{align*}
$$

And for other $x \neq h$, we have $(x - h)^2 + (0 - k)^2 = (x - h)^2 + r^2 > r^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us find the intersection of the circle with the $x$-axis ($y=0$).

Setting $y=0$ in the equation $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2,$$ we get $$x^2-2hx+h^2+k^2-r^2=0.$$

Each root represents the abscissa of one intersection.

For tangency, the coordinate of two intersections must coincide $\implies $ the roots of must be the same.

For the problem in the question, we have $(\alpha - h)^2 + (0 - k)^2 = r \Rightarrow  \alpha = h \pm \sqrt{r^2 - k^2}$. Then, since it intersects the $x$-axis at only one point, we must have $\sqrt{r^2 - k^2} = 0$, i.e. $r^2 = k^2$ or $r = \left|k\right|$.

Comment: What do you mean by "For tangency the coordinate of two intersections must coincide ⟹ the roots of must be same"?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius, the  roots of the quadratic equation will have to be same for the tangency

Comment: Ah, I get it now.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius, Find my other answer, too:)

Answer (score 0):

The distance of the tangent from the center = the radius

$$\frac{|k|}{\sqrt{0^2+1^2}}=r$$

Answer (score 0):

You've got a quadratic equation in $\alpha$ in terms of known constants $h$,$k$,$r$. So if circle *touches* x-axis, then what should you expect the solution to your quadratic equation to be? (in terms of its multipilicty). And then think about discriminant

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, you know that the radius of the circle is perpendicular to the tangent; since the tangent is horizontal, the radius to the intersection point must be vertical...